# Named rows and cols for matrices in R

Tags: r, matrix

Is it possible to have named rows and columns in `Matrices`?

for example:

```
    [,a] [,b]
[a,]  1 ,  2
[b,]  3 ,  4
```

Is it even reasonable to have such a thing for exploring the data?

Comment: @TylerRinker oh! you mean `dimnames`, right?

Comment: I have to use `?` more often! thanks Tyler! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure. Use `dimnames`:

```
> a <- matrix(1:4, nrow = 2)
> a
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4
> dimnames(a) <- list(c("A", "B"), c("AA", "BB"))
> a
  AA BB
A  1  3
B  2  4
```

With `dimnames`, you can provide a list of (first) `rownames` and (second) `colnames` for your matrix. Alternatively, you can specify `rownames(x) <- whatever` and `colnames(x) <- whatever`.